# Check if one string is a permutation of another using Python

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, complexity

The code below is an attempt at a solution to an exercise from the book "Cracking the Coding Interview."

I believe that the worst case time complexity of the code below is \$O(n)\$, where n is the length of each string (they should be the same length since I am checking if there lengths are equal) and the space complexity is \$O(n)\$.

Is this correct?  In particular does checking the length of each string take \$O(1)\$ time?

```
def is_permutation(first_string, other_string):
    if len(first_string) != len(other_string):
        return False

    count_first = {}
    count_other = {}

    for char in first_string:
        if char in count_first.keys():
            count_first[char] += 1
        else:
            count_first[char] = 1

    for char in other_string:
        if char in count_other.keys():
            count_other[char] += 1
        else:
            count_other[char] = 1

    for char in count_first.keys():
        if char not in count_other.keys():
            return False
        elif count_first[char] != count_other[char]:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Have you tested this code?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that. It's very obviously wrong.

Comment: I edited the code, and re-tested it.

Comment: I can't imagine `len()` might be more expensive than \$O(n)\$, and if it's \$O(n)\$ you don't need to worry about it. Your code must examine every character of both strings at least once, hence you no way can get better than \$O(n)\$, so the cost of `len()` doesn't matter in this context.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, [`len(str)` should be O(1) in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/1115313/1157100).  (Good question!)  Each of your `for` loops is O(*n*), so your whole function is O(*n*).

---

Your counting loops could be written more compactly as

```
for char in first_string:
    count_first[char] = 1 + count_first.get(char, 0)
```

The epilogue could be [simplified](//stackoverflow.com/a/4527957/1157100) to

```
return count_first == count_other
```

---

It pays to get familiar with the standard Python library, though.  Your entire function could be more simply implemented as

```
from collections import Counter

def is_permutation(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

… where `len(a) == len(b)` is an optional optimization.  Writing less code simplifies maintenance and tends to create fewer opportunities for introducing bugs (as in Rev 2 of your question).

Comment: _"Writing less code simplifies maintenance and tends to create fewer opportunities for introducing bugs_": Come over to code golf and you'll get some great tips on how to simplify maintenance. ;-P

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: Let's not get carried away here. There's a reason why I wrote "less code" instead of "shorter code", and included "tends to"!

Comment: is there a difference (computationally) between writing key in dict vs key in dict.key() ? What value does the function keys() add. Is that something worth learning?

Comment: @geekidharsh Not calling `dict.keys()` means that you save the work of [constructing a view of the keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Answer (score 3):

What I understand is that you want to know if 2 strings contain the same characters in the same quantity and not necessarily arranged similarly.

For example `"cat"` and `"act"` should return `true`.

You could check the length, then sort both strings and just compare them using `==`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/7sIoF4 Is this kind of implementation what you were talking about? Not sure about the big O notation in this example. I believe sort is O(n log n)

Comment: Yes, it's O(n log n), so less efficient even if more compact to write.

Comment: In practice, lots of Python code tends to be slow (by a constant factor), and `dict` operations can also be slow (by a constant factor), so the O(n log n) solution with a small constant factor can be faster than the O(n) solution. To figure out which one is faster for you, benchmark it for your typical inputs. Without the benchmark I'd go with the short solution `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`, because it's easier to understand what it does and that it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid the need for `count_other` and for the final loop.

Keep the first loop as it is, but in the second loop (i.e. `for char in other_string`), *remove* each character from `count_first`.  If you can't remove it, you have a character that's not in `first` so return false.

If you reach the end of the second loop, then you just need to check whether `count_first` is empty (i.e. all values are zero).

```
def is_permutation(first_string, other_string):
    if len(first_string) != len(other_string):
        return False

    count_first = {}

    for char in first_string:
        if char in count_first.keys():
            count_first[char] += 1
        else:
            count_first[char] = 1

    for char in other_string:
        if char not in count_first.keys():
            return False
        count_first[char] -= 1
        if count_first[char] < 0:
            return False

    for count in count_first.values():
        if count > 0:
            return False

    return True
```

This improves the original in two ways: it reduces the storage requirements, and it provides an earlier return in some of the negative cases.

---

You can eliminate the `if char in keys()` test in a number of ways:

- ```
  count_first.setdefault(0);
  ```
- use a `collections.defaultdict`, or better, `collections.Counter` instead of a `dict`

If we use a `Counter`, it's simple to compare the results:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_permutation(first_string, other_string):
    return Counter(first_string) == Counter(other_string)
```

Yes, that's the whole function!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Before checking these functions, you need to check `if len(str(n)) == len(str(m))`

```
def perm(n,m):
    return sorted(str(n)) == sorted(str(m))
```

```
%timeit perm(783169,781396)
1.25 µs ± 36.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit perm(783169123123123123123123,781396123123123123123123)
3.44 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit perm(783169123123123123123123,781396123123123123123123)
3.79 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `sorted()` function of string is the fastest *if the string size is small*.

```
def perm(n,m):
    n = [i for i in str(n)]
    for i in str(m):
        try:
            n.remove(i)
        except:
            return False
    return True
```

```
%timeit perm(783169,781396)
1.57 µs ± 46.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit perm(783169123123123123123123,781396123123123123123123)
4.77 µs ± 114 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Using a `List` instead of a `Dictionary` or `Counter()` is faster, since you don't always have to check for all the items.

```
def perm(n,m):
    n = collections.deque(str(n))
    for i in str(m):
        try:
            n.remove(i)
        except:
            return False
    return True
```

```
%timeit perm(783169,781396)
1.45 µs ± 38.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit perm(783169123123123123123123,781396123123123123123123)
3.28 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `deque()` function from the `collections` module is faster than `List` when it comes to popping items.

Even though `sorted()` is much faster than `deque()` for a small string, `deque()` is much faster for a longer string. These timings were calculated for the worst case scenario where the two strings are permutations of each other. For cases where this is not true, `deque()` would become even faster while `sorted()` would stay the same.

Comment: Those test strings are very short, and don't give any indication of how the code scales as they grow longer - but that's exactly what we need to know if we want to discuss big-O performance.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tested it for bigger strings and updated the post. As i guessed before, sorted is slower for longer strings